# Separate string into a set of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

I have this string `var string = "{name: Hello, age: 20}, {name: Nadia, age: 30}"` returned from the backend. I created an object out of it by appending it to an empty array like so:

```
var array = [];
var array1 = array.push(string);
```

After appending to an array, I got the following result:

```
Array [
      "{name: Hello, age: 20}, 
       {name: Nadia, age: 30}
       {name: Nadia, age: 30}
       {name: Nadia, age: 30}
       {name: Nadia, age: 30}"
]
```

My intended result is this:

```
Array [
          "{name: Hello, age: 20}", 
          "{name: Nadia, age: 30}",
          "{name: Nadia, age: 30}",
          "{name: Nadia, age: 30}",
          "{name: Nadia, age: 30}"
    ]
```

I have tried using `split(",")` but they're separated individually instead. How can I achieve the intended result? I'm very new to this.

**UPDATE:** The answer provided gave out not quite the result that I wanted. I have this larger set of objects. The solution returns me with 2 objects, with the second object being a combination of objects. Here's the output using the method in the answer:

```
Array [
          "{name: Hello, age: 20}", 
          "{name: Nadia, age: 30}
           {name: Nadia, age: 30}
           {name: Nadia, age: 30}
           {name: Nadia, age: 30}"
    ]
```

Also, I have asked my fellow backend dev to fix the json return, sadly they cannot change it. I'm not sure why. The only way I can handle this is on frontend.

Comment: Your input is essentially broken. Fix your backend so that it serves you proper JSON.

Comment: Ok thought so, I'm doing frontend and have been searching for hours for this. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below method works but its a bit crude. But you can give it a try..

```js
let str = "{name: Hello, age: 20}, {name: Nadia, age: 30}, {name: Nadia, age: 30}, {name: Nadia, age: 30}";
let x = str.replaceAll('}, ', '}/').split('/');
console.log(x);
```

Comment: i tried it and it just what i was looking for. but what do you mean crude?

Comment: I have just realised that this solution does not produce what i intended to. Sure it returns an array, only the first index is returned correctly. The subsequent data are returned as one chunk of objects. I'll update in the question

Comment: replace() works only for the first encounter. Changing it to replaceAll() should do the work. I have updated my answer, please verify it..

Comment: it works now as expected now, thanks. Wish i could upvote but I don't have enough reputation. Why does replace() only works on the first encounter?

Comment: this replaceAll() throws an error in typescript; undefined function. I have also tried adding /g but it was also no go. What else can i do for this....

Comment: this above error maybe due to old version of js/ts. Is replace working for u fine in ur code? If So then make this change: ```let x = str.replace(/}, /g, '}/').split('/');```.                   Now the replace function with global identifier regex will work in the same way as replaceAll.

Comment: And if replace is also saying undefined function in your ts. Try:                                                     ```let x = str.split('}, ').join('}/').split('/');```. This should do the work